# OAuth2.0 Access token validation by Resource server

Tags: validation, oauth-2.0, token

I am trying to implement OAuth2.0 authorization framework in one java based web project.
I use MS Azure as the Resource Owner(R.O) + Auth Server(A.S).

I also created some customized scopes(i.e. attributes) to be included in the Access token.

My question is - `when client receives access token from Azure AD and forwards it to the Resource Server, how does resource server(RS) validates this access token ? How can RS decode the token and read the "scope".`

The RS was never connected to R.O or A.S.

Note. I dont want to use OIDC. I want to achieve this only through OAuth2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are the two options I can see so far:

> 1. Client sends RS are pre-provisioned with client_id and client_secret.
>    Client_Id and client_secret shall be generated by
>    Azure AD when subscriber registers the APP.    When client sends
>    access token to RS, client also includes the "code" it received from
>    Azure AD (i.e. Resource Owner which is Azure AD). RS can now trigger a
>    GET request with the "code" + client_id. Azure AD can then issue an
>    access token back to the RS. Here RS can map the checksum and verify
>    if the access token is same(i.e. authorized).
> 2. Client sends access token to RS. RS decodes the token with base64 and only checks the expiry and client Id.
>    If the expiry is valid and client Id is same then RS concludes the token to be valid.

```
1st option seems to be more secured where RS can validate the access token and can also refresh the tokens if required.
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume token here you are referring is `JWT` token. Decoding `JWT` token is not a big deal, as the token is just Base64 encoded.

But the validating the token is important.

There are 2 ways the validate the token (the token is intact and not tempered in between):

1. If the token was signed using the symmetric algorithm (HS256, ...) then the same key needs to be with the RS as it was used by AS. I guess, in your case it won't be possible. Because you will not have a key with you.
2. If the token was signed using the asymmetric algorithm (RS256, ...). AS will use 'private key' to sign the token and RS will use corresponding public key to validate the token.

Note: the asymmetric key algorithm is CPU intensive task for RS to validate the token.

Comment: Yes,** jwt** token.   Decoding with symmetric algorithm looks a bit risky. The asymmetric algorithm looks better in terms of validation. Can you clarify how can  **private key** be fetched from Azure AD.

Comment: You need to check which algorithm is used to sign the token. If it is asymmetric then you need public key from the signer.